# Visual Basic RunSQL Syntax error using Tablesample

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form in Microsoft Access that imports records into a table from text files. The original code is this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE QC_File SET QC_File.ToQC = 'x' " & _
"WHERE (((QC_File.ID) In (Select TOP " & VarPer & " PERCENT ID " & _
"FROM QC_File As DUPE " & _
"WHERE [DUPE].[HIST_USUS_ID] = [QC_File].[HIST_USUS_ID] And [DUPE].[Client1] = 'CLIENT' " & _
"ORDER BY [DUPE].[ID] DESC;)))"`
```

This code is only grabbing the TOP 10 percent when I want it to pull a random 10 percent so I tried the following but I keep getting an error ("Syntax error in query expression"
) and it does not specify what line the error is occuring on, it just returns the whole code.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE QC_File SET QC_File.ToQC = 'x' " & _
"WHERE (((QC_File.ID) In (Select ID " & _
"FROM QC_File As DUPE Tablesample(10 PERCENT) " & _
"WHERE [DUPE].[HIST_USUS_ID] = [QC_File].[HIST_USUS_ID] And [DUPE].[Client1] = 'CLIENT' " & _
"ORDER BY [DUPE].[ID] DESC;)))"
```

I already tried using `NEWID()` but all that does is return the TOP 10 Percent in random order. Is it not possible to use the Tablesample command when writing SQL in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access will object to this `FROM` clause in the subquery:

```
FROM QC_File As DUPE Tablesample(10 PERCENT)
```

`Tablesample()` is not supported in Access SQL.

I suggest you build a new Access query which accomplishes what you want from the subquery.  Once that you have that working, use it as the subquery.